# how to I access vtk library functions in visual studio c++ code

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vtk

I have downloaded vtk and now I want to call it in my code in visual studio. How do I add the vtk library so I could call it easily.

Comment: Maybe follow their [instructions](https://vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Building/VisualStudio)??

Comment: I suggest you read this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=msvc-160), the second half of this document describes how to add a library to your project.